# How to convert a nested vector into set for rows but not for columns like vector<vector<int>> to set<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl, set

I've got a vector<vector> res which is [[-1,-1,2], [-1,-1,2], [1,0,1]] and I want to convert it to [[-1,-1,2], [1,0,1]]. How do I do it?

Comment: Try `set<vector<int>> S(V.cbegin(), V.cend())`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to convert to? From the example it appears you are just dropping the first row.

Comment: I want the rows to be unique. The same row should not be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of vector for this.

`set<vector<int> > st(v.begin(), v.end());`

Here v is the vector of vector.

If you want to check or display it. You can do the following:

```
for(auto it = st.begin(); it!=st.end(); it++)
{
    for(auto itr = (*it).begin(); itr!=(*it).end(); itr++)
        cout<<*itr<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```